# python combine split and join into 1 line of code

Tags: python, string, pandas, lambda

I am trying to combine a split and join into line of code where split only takes the first 3 words separated of the column.

```
df['c'] = df[['a']].apply(lambda x: x.str.split().str[:3])
df['c'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

I tried

```
df['c'] = df[['a']].apply(lambda x: ', '.join((x.str.split().str[:3])))
but keep getting an error.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `str` and `[]` for `Series`, so `apply` working with scalars:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join((x.split()[:3])))
```

List comprehension alternative:

```
df['c'] = [', '.join((x.split()[:3])) for x in df['a']]
```

Comment: awesome thanks! i tried to up vote but my rep is still low

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the Pandas `str` accessor or a list comprehension with regular Python `str` methods. The list comprehension is usually more efficient. You should limit your split to 3 to eliminate unnecessary operations.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ab cd ef gh ij', 'kl mn op qr', 'st uv', 'wx yz 123 456']})

df['B'] = df['A'].str.split(n=3).str[:3].str.join(', ')
df['C'] = [', '.join(x.split(maxsplit=3)[:3]) for x in df['A']]

assert df['B'].equals(df['C'])

print(df)

                A            B            C
0  ab cd ef gh ij   ab, cd, ef   ab, cd, ef
1     kl mn op qr   kl, mn, op   kl, mn, op
2           st uv       st, uv       st, uv
3   wx yz 123 456  wx, yz, 123  wx, yz, 123
```