# How to calculate the total count of characters in a python set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set

I initially had 1 doubt, but while writing this question I got another doubt.
So I have a dataset as follows:

[image]

A. I have used the following code to get the above data groupedby (apologies for not including the id column):

```
dff = df_new.groupby('id').agg({'brand':'first','title':'first','generic_keywords':'first',
                                  'revised_keywords': lambda x: set(x)})
```

so my 1st query is, how can I have the 'revised_keywords' without space after the commas ?
expected output would look something like this (here showing for just the 1st row):

```
{highland cow christmas ornament,cow tree ornament,highland cow christmas decoration,highland cow ornament,cow ornament tree}
```

Now coming to my 2nd query and main query, once I get the rows updated as above (without spaces after the commas), how can I calculate the total count of characters for each row ?
`len()` is just giving me the count of strings.

So the output looks something like this:

```
5
16
19
```

But the expected output would look something like this:

```
123
261
347
```

(calculated in excel without the spaces after each comma, but the spaces between the words and commas are calculated):

Can I please get some help on this ?

TIA

Comment: The spaces aren't part of the value. The value is a `set` object, not a string. When a set is printed, it's normally printed with comma+space between elements.

Comment: You can use `','.join(set(x))` to create a comma-delimited string.

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar it worked, also thank you for a proper explanation. Can you please help me with the next query of getting the total character count as well, if possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first issue which is comma-separated space can be resolved by simple modification in your lambda function by using `','.join(set(x))` because `set` is an object and it will print the content originally.

For the count issue, you can use

```
.apply(lambda x: sum(len(word) for words in x for word in words.split(',')))
```

This will help you in counting the alphabet.

This will also be helpful for you.

[helping material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502754/python-combine-split-and-join-into-1-line-of-code)

Comment: Thank you so much @Nimra, it is working, just one more doubt, the count that i am getting for the 1st row is 119, but the excel len() formula shows 123, (same count diff for all the rows) so just wanted to understand that, if possible

Comment: there might be issues with the spaces